# How to convert a Debian package into a homebrew formula?

Tags: debian, homebrew, apt, dpkg

There's a Debian package I'm interested in for which no `homebrew` formula yet exists.

How can I convert a `*.deb` package file into a `homebrew` formula?

(FWIW, the Debian package I'm interested in is for a simple Python-based app.  IOW, I don't expect that any compiling will be required, in case this makes a difference.)

Comment: Have you read the instructions on the Homebrew wiki?

Comment: I don't see anything [there](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tree/master/share/doc/homebrew#readme) that even remotely addresses my question.  If you have something specific in mind, please post a link to it.  BTW, I'm not asking how one makes a Homebrew formula.  I'm asking for an automated deb->homebrew conversion tool.

Comment: Such a thing does not exist. It's probably better to ask specifically about porting the one package mentioned in your question. Or just writing the formula yourself: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md

Comment: A converter for simple .deb packages would really cool. But there still doesn't seem to be one. In the meantime, the formula cookbook has now moved to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md